# How to solve $k^x = x!$ exactly

Tags: logarithms

For the sake of simplicity let's take $k = 51$, how do I proceed without applying the Sterling's log approximation. I'm looking for a way to find an exact answer. Thank you.

Comment: What is supposed to be $x!$ ,where $x \in \mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: @openspace, $x\notin\Bbb Z$ obviously, as $x!$ is even for all $x\ge2, x\in\Bbb Z$, while $51^x$ is most certainly odd.

Comment: @RhysHughes I mean how do we want to determine $x!$ for $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Oh I see, different notation. My apologies

Comment: @openspace there is a way to define the factorial for real numbers, through an integral.

Comment: If $x$ and $k$ are natural numbers that satisfy $k^x = x!$, then $(x,k) = (0,0),\,(0,1),\,(1,1)$. If $k$ is a real number, $k = (x!)^{1/x}$. If $x$ is a real number, you're going to need to specify which extension of $x!$ to the reals you want to use.

Comment: @RGS that's would be gamma function, am I right? I mean that's not the definition of factorial. Gamma function is more general.